# How to indent inward a block of text by a TAB or 4 spaces, in Emacs, in markdown-mode?

Tags: emacs, indentation, markdown

How to indent inward a block of text by a TAB or 4 spaces, in Emacs, in markdown-mode?

I mean manually triggering that for selected text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `C-u C-x C-i` will indent the marked block by 4 spaces (`C-x C-i` => `indent-rigidly`, `C-u` without following digits or minus sign => the implicit universal argument of 4).  (First mark one end of the block with `C-SPC` and then move to the other end of the block, in case "marked" isn't a familiar concept.)

Judging from http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/, if you want to indent the block that way to mark it as code, you want `C-c C-s c` (after marking the block as above).

Comment: This only works when `cua-mode` is disabled. Any way of doing the same thing when `cua-mode` is on?

Comment: I don't have any first-hand experience with `cua-mode`, but looking at its documentation, you need to press the `C-x` twice within 0.2 seconds or follow `C-x` with `C-i` within 0.2 seconds or use the shift key, too, so `C-X`.  Or invoke the command by name, like `C-u M-x indent-rigidly`.